# Joins Across Several Tables (HABTM, Rails, Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

This is a conceptual question, not a gimme the code question.

I'm working with 4 models:  `Doctor, Specialization, School, Service`

Doctor has mutual HABTM associations with the other 3 models, and 3 joins tables have been created to hold these associations:

```
doctors_specializations
doctors_schools
doctors_services
```

Queries from front-end users will need to access all doctors with specified criteria held in the other 3 tables.

Example:  Return all doctors who went to Harvard, specialize in face lifts, and offer some type of related ancillary service.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Better to have only Doctor model and you can have 3 flags with each case.
And you can create 3 scopes in Doctor model with the 3 cases you have.

```
scope :specialized, where(specialized: true)
```